# Angular 4 NgModule - Inject service with target class name into another service

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I would like to know if there is a way to access the target class name during Angular 4 dependency injection. I'm trying to do that because I would like my logging system to know the source of the logging and print it without having to specify it every time.

Here's some context to my problem:

**This is a snippet of my logger**

```
@Injectable()
export class Logger {
    constructor(private source: string, (...)) { }
}
```

**This is a snippet of my service**

```
@Injectable()
export class SomeService {
    constructor(private logger: Logger, (...)) {
        // I know i could initialize the logger here and set the name of the service, but I would like to do it by injection, if possible
    }
}
```

**What I would like to do**

```
export function factoryFunc() {
    return (injectionContext : InjectionContext): string => {

        /* InjectionContext doesn't exist, its just theorical and to explain
           what I'm trying to achieve, which is to access an injection context in
           the factory func and the target class name
        */
        var className = injectionContext.getInjectionTargetClassName();
        return new Logger(className);
    };
};


@NgModule({
    (...),
    providers: [
        SomeService,
        { provide: Logger , useFactory: factoryFunc() },
    ]
})
```

Comment: It's not possible to identify an injectable by class name, this is the whole idea behind identifying them by classes. Moreover, Logger is a singleton, it will be instantiated only once.